# Rails Secret URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a registration-optional Rails app. For the sake of simplicity, let's say it's a pastebin (could also be something like a URL shortener). I want each paste to accessible from two URLs: one with read-only access for sharing with others and one with edit access for the original creator of the paste.

So far I've tried doing this by creating two keys in my Paste model:
:show_id, :edit_id

I have a method that runs on the before_validation :on => create callback that generates these two random strings for these keys.

I set up some routes so that '/s/show_id' and '/e/:edit_id' go to the corresponding controllers.

Now I'd like to have the 'resources' route helper methods (ex: paste_path, edit_paste_path) point to these URLs and not the default ones. It seems, though, that I need to override the to_param method to do this, but I'm not sure how I might get it to output the :show_id or :edit_id correctly.

Comment: For clarification: are you using any sort of user authentication inside your app as well?  I'd love to see you just have the one url and some kind of authentication take care of showing the edit/delete actions inside.

Comment: Yeah, I am using some user authentication, but as I said, I'm planning on making registration optional. One option that I'm now considering is to make editing available only for registered users.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding to_param won't work, because it assumes that the record has a single identifier. I'd try redefining paste_path and edit_path_path themselves. Something like...

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def paste_path(paste)
    "/s/#{paste.show_id}"
  end

  def edit_paste_path(paste)
    "/e/#{paste.edit_id}"
  end
end
```

Note that this will just handle the simplest use-case. You might want to handle extra options in the helpers, or also handle paste_url, or handle something like url_for([:edit, paste]), etc, but this is where I'd start.